# Where does python store an imported function's global scope variables?

Tags: python-3.x, scope, global-variables, python-import

I'm study python scope today and did some experiments.
And I found an interesting phenomenon. That by calling `exec("global var; var = value")` inside an imported function. I can store this value in somewhere unknown. And later on I can retrieve it by using `import module; print(module.var)`. Please see the code below:

```
# temp.py
def str_to_global_var(string, obj):
    command_1 = 'global %s; %s=%r' % (string, string, obj)
    exec(command_1)



# script.py
from copy import copy
from temp import str_to_global_var

cur_global = copy(globals())
str_to_global_var('x', 6)

new_global = globals()

print(set(new_global.keys()) - set(cur_global.keys()))

d2 = copy(new_global)
d1 = copy(cur_global)

del d2['cur_global']
del d2['new_global']

print('Compare d2==d1: ', d2 == d1)
print("'x' in new_global: ",'x' in new_global)

import temp
print("temp.x:", temp.x)



# Interpreter running result
>>> ipython3 script.py

{'new_global', 'cur_global'}
Compare d2==d1:  True
'x' in new_global:  False
temp.x: 6
```

I did a shallow copy of script.py's globals() before and after using `str_to_global_var` function(deepcopy will fail). They are comparing equal after remove 2 irrelevant identifier "new_global" and "cur_global", so it is said at the shallow copy level, the interpreter thought nothing changed  in script.py's global scope after using the imported `str_to_global_var` function, as we all know it only updates a global variable to temp.py's scope.

But the question is, before we using `import temp.py; print(temp.var)`  statement.
Where did python stored this `temp.var`'s value?
How could I access it?
 And If I want to make the imported `str_to_global_var` function to update globals for script.py, is there a trick to modify its attribute so that python will recognize it as a function of script.py?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an example of str_to_global that works on the calling module using **sys._getframe**:

```
#a.py
def str_to_global(name, value):
    sys._getframe(1).f_globals[name] = value

#b.py
from a import str_to_global
str_to_global('cheese', 'cake')
print(cheese)
```

> cake

Answer (score 3):

When your code gets executed

```
def str_to_global_var(string, obj):
    command_1 = 'global %s; %s=%r' % (string, string, obj)
    exec(command_1)
```

by calling

```
str_to_global_var('x', 6)
```

The global variable gets created in the module temp. You can confirm that by using below

```
print ('x' in str_to_global_var.__globals__)
print (str_to_global_var.__globals__['x'])
```

The output will be

```
True
6
```

By default you can't modify the context of the current module from another module. So if you have below code

```
x = 10
str_to_global_var('x', 6)
print ("x = " + str(x))
```

The output will be

```
x = 10
```

If you want to modify variables in current module context then you need to pass that context also to the function

```
def str_to_global_var2(globalsvar, string, obj):
    command_1 = 'globalsvar["%s"] = %r' % (string, obj)
    exec(command_1)
```

And then call it like below

```
x = 10
str_to_global_var2(globals(), 'x', 6)
print ("x = " + str(x))
```

The output will be

```
x = 6
```

The function can be simplified as

```
def str_to_global_var3(globalsvar, string, obj):
    globalsvar[string] = obj
```

Comment: Thank you. There is still one doubt in the question unsolved. Is there some kind of trick can help me to make `str_to_global_var` a function of script.py, by modifying some special attributes in interactive prompt?

Comment: By the way, there is a bug in your newly wrote function `str_to_global_var2`
. In which the `command_1` should be `"%r[%s] = %r" % (global_vars, string, obj)` instead of   `'globalsvar["%s"] = %r' % (string, obj)`